# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" with escaped quotes in string

Tags: javascript

When I'm tries to open a saved blog posts with jQuery I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on line 220. Line 220 is `Hans kommande film som har premiär nu på...`. Please see full code copied from Google Chromes console below.

```
    $('body').on('click', '#load-blogpost-ill-be-back', function() {

        var subject = "I\'ll be back!";
        var message = "[url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000216/]Arnold Schwarzenegger[/url] är en sann legendar när det gäller kända repliker och karriär. I alla fall för min del. Hans \"I\'ll be back!\" i första [url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/]Terminator[/url], är en klar klassiker som används ofta i all möjlig media, bilder som filmer. Jag tittade nyss på en [url=http://instagram.com/p/Ugz4LBDcfx/]Instagram-bild[/url] som han hade delat ut på Facebook, såg man att han börjar på att bli en gammal man. En gammal man i äkta papparoll-stuk, vilket gillas. I alla fall av mig :)

Hans kommande film som har premiär nu på fredag i [url=http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA]USA[/url], [url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1549920/]The Last Stand[/url], verkar för övrigt vara en väldigt lovande film med många kända skådespelare; [url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0424216/]Johnny Knoxville[/url], [url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0350079/]Luis Guzmán[/url], [url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001780/]Peter Stormare[/url], [url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001845/]Forest Whitaker[/url] och såklart våran kära Arnold som har huvudrollen i filmen. Titta på filmen förhandstitt nedan.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier


[yt]https://www.youtube.com/embed/BS-FyAh9cv8[/yt]";

        $(this).replaceWith(subject);
        $('input[name="textfield-subject"]').val(subject);
        $('textarea[name="textarea-message"]').val(message).focus();

        // VISA
        $('.blogpost-preview-ruler').show();
        $('#blogpost-preview-head').show();

        // VISA & SKRIV UT
        $('#blogpost-preview-subject').show().html(subject);
        $('#blogpost-preview').show().html(bbcode_js(message));


        var selectedID = [];
        $(':checkbox[name="checkbox[]"]').each(function() {
                            if($(this).val() == '4') {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                }
                    });

    });
```

What's wrong with that line? Is it the `/` in the links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that JavaScript doesn't support multi-line strings like that. You either have to end each line with a `\` (not recommended since a space afterwards also produces a syntax error) or to use concatenation.

E.g., (notice they are two separate strings concatinated together and `\n` injected.)

```
var message = "[url=http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000216/]Arnold Schwarzenegger[/url] är en sann legendar när det gäller kända repliker och karriär. ... :)\n\n" +
          "Hans kommande film som har premiär nu på fredag i [url=http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA]USA[/url], [url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1549920/]The Last Stand[/url], ...";
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it to work in my code. I'll start a new question about it since the string I'm getting the data from is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode()` is a good method to make a string inside a PHP variable available for Javascript.

```
echo "var message = ". json_encode($your_string_var_here);
```