# Replace every new line to output the data correctly

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace every new line with `"\n\n + "` in order to [eliminate this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345662/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-with-escaped-quotes-in-string/14345768#14345768). I'm only want to get the last data in the database, so I am using PHP to get the subject and the message for my saved blog post. This is working very fine but it outputs the data for the content of the blog post wrong.

In order to correct this, I must somehow replace every new line in my blog post with `"\n\n + "` and what I can come think of is `str_replace` but it will not change the new lines to what I want. Here is how I have done so far:

`str_replace("/\r\n/", '"\n\n + "', addslashes($saved_blogpost['data_message']))`

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality you want to use `json_encode()`, and not mess with the string.

Comment: Thanks! That worked quite well but I'm just getting `null` with this: `json_encode(addslashes($saved_blogpost['data_message']))` and even if I remove `addslashes`. Why?

Comment: well what does addslashes do and to what? Looks like you are on a symptom fixing chain to me.

Comment: `addslashes` adds slashes to `"` and `'`. Maybe to something more character. I don't know. Na. I just have some problems and I want to fix them but can't fix them alone. That's all.

Comment: You haven't looked at your original question. I did not mention using addslashes there. Why you get "null"? Probably because the variable is null or undefined. Do you get notices from PHP? `error_reporting(E_ALL)` will help you during development.

Comment: I know. I have removed `addslashes` but the same response keep coming: `null`. If I turn `E_ALL` on I'm getting errors like everywhere about like everything but the source code looks all fine. It seems that I must use `global` or something like that for almost everything I have done. I didn't find any errors that is related to my problem though.

Comment: I dont know your code, so I cannot help with this, but it is a bad sign of lazy development style, and you should fix it.

Comment: I know. I will fix all errors when I can :) Thanks anyway for your help. I'll accept it.